# Calling member of derived class from Base reference object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I found many similar questions on SO, but their solution is either not working or it's slightly different (often using pointers instead, I do not want to change the caller() signature!). If this has already been asked (and answered) please let me know and I'll delete this question.

I found something called the *visitor pattern* but I'm curious if there is a simpler solution. I try do do it without using `virtual` since my course did not cover that yet. Or do I need it here?

I have the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void fun(); // cout << "Base"
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void fun(); // cout << "Derived"
};

void caller(Base &obj)   // must stay as it is
{
    // here i want to call Derived::fun()
    // obj.fun() prints 'Base' but I need 'Derived'
}

int main()
{
    // Base base;
    // caller(base);

    // EDIT:
    Derived derived;
    caller(derived);

}
```

What would be the easiest way to have caller() call Derived::fun() instead of Base::fun() when passing a `Base &` to the function caller()?

If there's a simple answer pointing me in the right direction would be highly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while now:)

**I know that this is not something you would do in production code, this is about learning C++**

**EDIT: I changed the caller function argument to type `Derived` instead of `Base`**

Comment: Do you know about polymorphism?

Comment: You are creating an object of type `Base`, not of type `Derived`. You cannot (even with `virtual` functions) call a derived class member function on an object of the base class. Why do you want to do that in the first place? Why are you not creating an object of `Derived` and let `caller` take a `Derived&`?

Comment: There is no `Derived`-object. So you can never call `Dervied::fun`

Comment: The "easiest way" is using "virtual" functions. However, the object in your `main` function is `Base` type, so whatever you want to do, you still will have a `Base` object.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I know what it is, but it wasn't covered thoroughly yet. What are you aiming at?

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. What are you actually trying to do here? Why do you need to call a `Derived` function on a `Base` object?

Comment: @scohe001 Yes, this is a 'puzzle' problem, I'm not trying to do more than I'm showing above. Part of the question asks why this is bad practice, but I can't even get it to work.

Comment: @rezi The only legal way to call the Derived `fun` modifying only the `caller` function's body is to create a new `Derived` object and call on that: `Derived{}.fun();` or `Derived d; d.fun();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It is not possible to call a `Derived` member function on a `Base` class object.

Every `Derived` is a `Base`, but a `Base` is not a `Derived`. In other words, `Derived` may have a whole bunch of information that `Base` lacks. **You may call a `Base` member function on a `Derived` class object, but not the other way**.

In other words...

```
class Base {
    public: void b_thing() { }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public: void d_thing() { }
};

int main() {
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    
    d.b_thing(); // Okay!
    b.d_thing(); // Bad :(
}
```

However, you can have a `Base` reference that references a `Derived` object:

```
Base &b_ref = d;
```

And since this is actually a `Derived` object, you can have it call `Derived` member functions (that were declared `virtual` in `Base`) via polymorphism:

```
class Base {
    public: virtual int thing() { return 0; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public: int thing() { return 1; }
};

int caller(Base &obj)
{
    return obj.thing(); // Returns 1 if obj actually references a Derived object
}

int main() {
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    
    caller(d); // 1
    caller(b); // 0
}
```

However, notice that when passed a `Base` object (when `obj` is actually referencing a `Base` object), we still call the `Base` member function.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  `caller` is given a reference to an actual `Base` object.  There is no way in C++ to convert this to a reference to a `Derived` object (because the object actually is *not* a `Derived` object).  Any attempt to do the conversion will fall foul of *Undefined Behaviour*.  This means that anything may happen.  Specifically, the call may appear to work - except when you come to do the demonstration to a major customer at which point it formats your hard disk instead.  (This is a slight exaggeration for rhetorical purposes; but undefined behaviour *has* turned a for loop running up to 64 into an infinite loop).

---

If we change `main` slightly, then this becomes a much more interesting question:

```
int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    caller(derived);

}
```

Now we *can* arrange to call `Derived::fun`.  The *best* solution is to make `fun` a virtual function.  Then it just works:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base"; }
};
```

The call to `obj.fun` will be directed to `Derived::fun` (like you wanted), and the code will print "derived".

That's great - and definitely should be your first port of call.  However maybe you can't change `Base`.  In that case, are *any* of the functions (like the destructor) virtual?  If so, we can use `dynamic_cast`:

```
void caller(Base &obj)   // must stay as it is
{
    Derived& d_ref = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(obj);
    d_ref.fun();
}
```

The nice thing about this, is that if `obj` is not *actually* a `Derived` object, the dynamic_cast will throw `std::invalid_cast`, and you don't get undefined behaviour.

Finally, maybe you can't change `Base`, *and* there are no virtual functions.  In that case, your only option is to reach for the blunderbuss of `static_cast` - however, be warned, this is how C++ programmers not merely shoot themselves in the foot, but blow their whole leg off.  (It's not quite as bad as the plasma cannon of `reintepret_cast`, but you really don't want to use it like this unless you have to.)

```
void caller(Base &obj)   // must stay as it is
{
    Derived& d_ref = static_cast<Derived&>(obj);
    d_ref.fun();
}
```

One can have to write this sort of thing in production code, but often `Base` has some sort of "what kind of thing am I" indicator, and you can check that before using the `static_cast`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I would change the main function so that it passes an `Derived` object would that change the answer? This is the only part the question isn't explicit about.

Comment: @rezi If you create and pass a `Derived` object in `main`, then the methods described in Vlad's answer apply. But if you use the `reinterpret_cast` method and do *not* pass a `Derived` object to it, you will have undefined behavior without any warning.

Comment: @rezi - Yes.  Very much.  However, leave the question as is (it would invalidate my answer, which I consider a useful rant against trying to do the impossible).  I'll extend the answer to include that anyway.

Comment: Actually `reinterpret_cast` is not required. `static_cast` will also do it while disallowing accidental casts to unrelated class types.

Comment: @walnut Aaaargh!  What on earth was I thinking?  Thank you.

Comment: @scohe001 Comment I wanted to post on the deleted answer: Yes it works if there is a virtual member function making the type polymorphic as also described in this answer. But then you can probably also just make `f` virtual and call it directly as well. If there are no virtual member functions, then it doesn't work.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I actually had to check whether it does. It seems like a very unsafe cast for `static_cast`, but it does allow it and is consistent with `static_cast` allowing the inverse of standard conversion sequences.

Comment: @walnut I realized what you meant with that right after they deleted their answer. You're entirely right, yes.

Comment: @walnut Actually it is vital to use `static_cast` here.  If `Derived` was declared as `class Derived: public OtherBase, Base ...` then `static_cast` will do the offset conversion correctly - `reinterpret_cast` won't.